# NSTextField keeps repeating title

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I created a new OSX application with Swift.  Start with a view, dragged in a Table View into the view.  Then I ctrl-clicked and dragged from my Table View to add AppDelegate as my `dataSource` and `delegate`.  Finally, ctrl-clicked and dragged from AppDelegate to create an IBOutlet for `myTableView` to the table view.

Why is this happening?  Using XCode Version 6.1 (6A1027).

Building the following results in this:[image: Results]

```
import Cocoa    
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: NSTableView!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    }

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(aTableView: NSTableView!) -> Int
    {
        let numberOfRows:Int = getDataArray().count
        return numberOfRows
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row rowIndex: Int) -> AnyObject!
    {
        var newString: (AnyObject?) = getDataArray().objectAtIndex(rowIndex).objectForKey(tableColumn.identifier)
        println(newString!)
        return newString!
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func getDataArray () -> NSArray{
        var dataArray:[NSDictionary] = [["FirstName": "Debasis", "LastName": "Das"],
            ["FirstName": "Nishant", "LastName": "Singh"],
            ["FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Doe"],
            ["FirstName": "Jane", "LastName": "Doe"],
            ["FirstName": "Mary", "LastName": "Jane"]];
        //println(dataArray);
        return dataArray;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which version of Xcode beta are you on?

Comment: Using XCode Version 6.1 (6A1027).

Answer (score 2):

There was a Table View Cell also being added when I dragged in the Table View along with the text cell.  I'm really not sure why, but this answer from 2 years ago helped me figure it out. [NSTableView only displaying "Table View Cell"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533682/nstableview-only-displaying-table-view-cell)

Comment: So others don't have to navigate there: select the Outline/Table View, then in the Attributes inspector area under "Table View", change Content Mode to be "Cell Based". That fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that "objectValueForTableColumn" only works if there's no other cell besides it. As Xcode6.1 automatically creates one, this method doesn't work anymore *unless you remove the new cell*.

To keep these cells and even add more, we should use "viewForTableColumn" instead: in IB, I named my table cell view "custom" then created a NSTableCellView to target it.

I also added another cell in IB, an ImageView, to illustrate my example.

```
let myQuotes: [String] = ["text field inside cell one", "number two", "here's the tird", "four: a fourth one", "five: and a last one"]

func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView!) -> Int {
    return myQuotes.count
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> NSView! {

    var result: NSTableCellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("custom", owner: self) as NSTableCellView

    result.textField.stringValue = myQuotes[row]

    let myAvatar: NSImage = NSImage(byReferencingFile: "Pictures/avatar.png")

    result.imageView.image = myAvatar

    return result

}
```

I got this working after having jumped around [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043090/nstableview-table-column-with-rich-formatted-text-and-image?lq=1) and this Objective-C [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html) for some time.

Comment: Switching to `viewForTableColumn` finally resolved this for me -- +1