# NSOutlineView - object value is being returned, but only the placeholder title "Table View Cell" is displayed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I am writing a small application tentatively called "CocoaMix", the purpose of which is to test out code that I have written for accessing the accessibility hierarchy on various UIs.  Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is an `NSOutlineView` on the left and an "example" view on the right of a test user interface.

So far, for the data source implementation I have:

```
@interface CMTopLevelCategory : NSObject

@property (readonly) NSString *name;

@property (readonly) NSArray *examples;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name examples:(NSArray *)examples;

@end


@interface CMExample : NSObject

@property (readonly) NSString *name;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name;

@end


@interface CMSideOutlineViewDataSource : NSObject <NSOutlineViewDataSource>

@end


//...


#define CMNameColumnIdentifier @"name"
#define CMCountColumnIdentifier @"count"

@interface CMSideOutlineViewDataSource ()

@property NSArray *topLevelCategories;

@end

@implementation CMSideOutlineViewDataSource

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        CMExample *largeTableExample = [[CMExample alloc] initWithName:@"Large Table"];
        CMTopLevelCategory *tablesCategory = [[CMTopLevelCategory alloc] initWithName:@"Tables" examples:@[ largeTableExample ]];

        _topLevelCategories = @[ tablesCategory ];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item {
    if (item) {
        if ([item isKindOfClass:CMTopLevelCategory.class]) {
            CMTopLevelCategory *topLevelCategory = item;
            return [topLevelCategory.examples objectAtIndex:index];
        }
    } else {
        return [self.topLevelCategories objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item {
    return [item isKindOfClass:CMTopLevelCategory.class];
}

- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item {
    if (item) {
        if ([item isKindOfClass:CMTopLevelCategory.class]) {
            CMTopLevelCategory *topLevelCategory = item;
            return [topLevelCategory.examples count];
        }
    } else {
        return [self.topLevelCategories count];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
    if ([item isKindOfClass:CMTopLevelCategory.class]) {
        CMTopLevelCategory *topLevelCategory = item;
        if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:CMNameColumnIdentifier]) {
            return topLevelCategory.name;
        } else if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:CMCountColumnIdentifier]) {
            return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[topLevelCategory.examples count]];
        }
    } else if ([item isKindOfClass:CMExample.class]) {
        CMExample *example = item;
        if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:CMNameColumnIdentifier]) {
            return example.name;
        }
    }
    return @"default value";
}

@end
```

To explain this, the top level items are supposed to be categories of examples like "Tables", and then for each category there are going to be some example UIs (e.g. "Large Table" in the "Tables" category of examples).

When I build and run, breakpoints that I have set in `outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:` are triggered, but the text in the `NSOutlineView` is still the placeholder "Table Cell View" text:

[image: Screenshot of the "CocoaMix" application window]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a view-based outline view? What is the view sub-hierarchy for each table cell? For example, is cell view an instance of `NSTableCellView` containing an `NSTextField`? Or is it just a bare `NSTextField`? Did you set up bindings within the table cell view sub-hierarchy? If so, explain the bindings that you set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to take some guesses. You're probably using a view-based outline view. The cell views are probably `NSTableCellView`s with an `NSTextField` in each.

The outline view takes the object value that your data source returns from its `-outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:` method and it calls `-setObjectValue:` on the cell view, if it responds to that method. `NSTableCellView` does.

So, now your table cell view has had its `objectValue` set. What does that do? Possibly nothing.

You can use bindings to bind the subviews to the table cell view, with key paths which go through the `objectValue`. So, you could bind the Value binding of your text field to the table cell view with a key path of `objectValue`. That would result in the text field showing the value.

Another approach is to subclass `NSTableCellView` and use that custom subclass as the cell view in your outline view. Then, override `-setObjectValue:` and, in addition to calling through to `super`, you could pass the object value on to the subviews. To access the subviews, you could connect them to the standard `textField` and `imageView` outlets of `NSTableCellView` or you could add more outlets to your custom subclass, connect them in IB, and use those.

The bindings approach is easiest, I think. Also, it provides more flexibility. Your implementation of `-outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:` could just return the `item`. Then, the binding of your text field could use `objectValue.name` as the model key path. If you add more subviews, they could use different key paths to show different aspects of the item.

For the different columns, you would use different cell view sub-hierarchies and the bindings of the subviews of those would use different key paths but the same `objectValue`. The idea is that the row represents a given item, so the `objectValue` would be that item, and the columns would just use different properties from the item.

Another possible approach, if you're sure your outline view is going to only have text fields in the cell views, is to not use `NSTableCellView` (or a subclass), at all. Instead, use bare `NSTextField`s for your cell views. In that case, when the outline view calls `-setObjectValue:` on the cell view, that will be the text field (which responds to that method), and will set its value with no extra steps.

Comment: Thank you for this! I don't understand all of it right now (I am just learning Cocoa), but I think that this answers my question. Yes, the cell views appear to be `NSTableCellView`s with an `NSTextField` in each. This was created for me by Interface Builder.

Comment: In Interface Builder's document outline, for each column I had a "Table Cell View" containing a "Table View Cell". I dragged the "Table View Cell" out from under the "Table Cell View", and made it a direct child of the column object. I then deleted the "Table Cell View". This worked! I think that this is the last approach you mentioned: using bare `NSTextField`s.

Answer (score 1):

Change the NSOutlineView's Content Mode to Cell Based as JAWZapps explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533682/nstableview-only-displaying-table-view-cell/10721771#10721771).

Answer (score 0):

with the reference of @Ken I am attaching of screenshot here.

1. Select your tableViewcell.
2. Go to binding inspector.
3. Tick on "bind to" to tableCellView
   [image]