# Xcode 6.1?? Why does the NSTableView show only placeholder text?

Tags: xcode

I have been debating for a while on the upgrade to 6.1 and finally decided to do it - it may have been a mistake.

I have several `NSTableViews` bound to `NSArrayController`s - all has been working well. After the upgrade, I added a new `NSTableView` and bound the table columns as usually and nothing!! only the place holder text "Table View Cell" appears in the cells.

I reinstalled Xcode 5, opened the project, and I can add a new `NSTableView` and bind to the `NSArrayController` and everything works fine.

Does anyone know what is going on? Do you have to bind the columns differently in 6.1?

Comment: What's up with the negative vote? I spent 4 hours researching this last night before posting (Reading document, looking for similar posts, etc...). I did found a post here with a similar issue and tried their solution - it did not work. I posted hoping to get some assistance from some more experienced programmers as I am still learning. Guess this isn't the place for beginners:-(

Comment: The difference is probably that the table view that you drag out in Interface Builder is defaulting to view-based in Xcode 6 while it was defaulting to `NSCell`-based in Xcode 5. There's a checkbox on the Attributes inspector for the table view to control that. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330468/nsoutlineview-object-value-is-being-returned-but-only-the-placeholder-title/26331214#26331214) for why a view-based table (or outline) view would only show the placeholder text.

Comment: @KenThomases : Thank you for the response, that was it, the default is set to view-based. If you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 5 and earlier, when you drag a table view out of the Object library in Interface Builder, it is an `NSCell`-based table view by default. In Xcode 6 and later, it's a view-based table view by default, with the cell views being `NSTableCellView`s with `NSTextField`s as subviews.

You can configure the "content mode" of the table view on the Attributes inspector at any time.

Furthermore, with that configuration for the cell view sub-hierarchy, you need to take extra steps to make the object value for the cell reflected in the actual cell views. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330468/nsoutlineview-object-value-is-being-returned-but-only-the-placeholder-title/26331214#26331214) for the details.