# Populate an NSTableView using an array - bind table

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6

Helo !

I have a problem with display some data from an array to a NSTableView . 
I have  my info saved in core data. I take this info and add to an array, but when i try to add this info in table, all what i receive is a table with correct numbers of rows, but all have the same implicit text : "TableView Cell"  .

For every table column i've set an identifier , and my binds, i think, they are made correctly. 
Here is my code for Table Controller :

```
  @IBAction func reload(sender: NSButton) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func getItemsFromDataBase() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyData")

    // Create a sort descriptor object that sorts on the "title"
    // property of the Core Data object
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nume", ascending: true)

    // Set the list of sort descriptors in the fetch request,
    // so it includes the sort descriptor
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [MyData] {
        for var i = 0 ; i < fetchResults.count  ; i++ {
            objects.append(fetchResults[i])   //Get  data  from database and put in array

        }
    }

}

 func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    getItemsFromDataBase()
    showNames()
    return objects.count
}




func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? {

    let identifier = tableColumn?.identifier
    println(identifier!)

    if let propertyEnum = ArrayDisplayProperty(rawValue: identifier!) {
        let cellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(identifier!, owner: self) as NSTableCellView

        let object = objects[row]

        switch propertyEnum {
        case .Nume:
            cellView.textField!.stringValue = object.nume
        case .Prenume:
            cellView.textField!.stringValue =  object.prenume
        case .Varsta:
            cellView.textField!.stringValue = "\(object.varsta)"
        case .Localitate :
            cellView.textField?.stringValue = object.localitate
        case .Major:
            cellView.textField?.stringValue = object.major == 1 ? "Yes" : "No"
        }

        println(object.nume)

        return object.varsta
    }

 return 0
}
```

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330468/nsoutlineview-object-value-is-being-returned-but-only-the-placeholder-title/26331214#26331214).

Answer (score 1):

Have you bounded only that table column or also that columns Text Field and Text Field Cell? 
Both of these Value need to be bounded to Table Cell View with model key path (let say you have entity Person with attribute 'name') `objectValue.name`. Xcode shows some warning 'cannot resolve the entered key path', but I think that can be ignored.

So example, if I have that entity `Person` with only one attribute `name`, my bindings looks like following with Array Controller:

Table View -> Table Content -> Content -> Bind to Array Controller with controller key arrangedObjects

Name column -> Value > Bind to Array Controller with controller key `arrangedObjects` and Model Key Path `name`

Text Field -> Value -> Bind to Table Cell View with model key path `objectValue.name`

Text Field Cell -> Value -> Bind to Table Cell View with model key path `objectValue.name`

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT Code**:--

Follow the steps for populating the data in `NSTableView` through `bindings`:-

1) Connect your ArrayController to your FileOwner/Appdelegate:-

[image]

2) Select your TableColumns and bind to ArrayController -> arrangedObjects -> Key

[image]

3) Now in your method follow below code:-

```
@IBOutlet weak var arrController : NSArrayController!

var yourArray: NSMutableArray = []

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    var dataArray = [["FirstName": "Debasis", "LastName": "Das"],
        ["FirstName": "Nishant", "LastName": "Singh"],
        ["FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Doe"],
        ["FirstName": "Jane", "LastName": "Doe"],
        ["FirstName": "Mary", "LastName": "Jane"]];


    for var i = 0; i < dataArray.count; i++
    {
        yourArray.addObject(dataArray[i])
    }
    arrController.rearrangeObjects()
}
```